# Добавить класс, чтобы не удалялся

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть две кнопки-ссылки

```
<a href="[[~160]]" class="pad5">
Избранные
</a>
<a href="[[~161]]"  class="pad5">Черный список
</a>
```

как сделать, чтобы при клике на них, им добавлялся класс, и после редиректа, класс не удалялся

пробовал так. но после нажатия на ссылку, класс добавляется, происходит редирект и класс удаляется

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".pad5").click(function(e) {
  $(".pad5").removeClass('btn-primary');
  $(this).toggleClass('btn-primary');
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: можно проверить на сервере или клиенте какая страница и поставить нужный класс

Comment: а можно в скрипте узнавать какая страница и добавить класс?

Comment: конечно можно!!!

Comment: var x = location.href; Узнали урку , и в зависимости какая урка сделали что нужно

Comment: сделал так

<script>
var x = location.href;
alert (x);
if (x=='izbrannyie') {
$('.izb').AddClass('btn-primary');
}

</script>

но не добавляет класс

Comment: @Aslero, во-первых, нет функции `AddClass`, есть `addClass`, во-вторых, посмотри чему у тебя равен `x`

Comment: блин addClass  cпасибо